# Can a person be banned from flying within the U.S. if he has a criminal record?

Tags: usa, air-travel, criminal-records

My ex-son-in-law insists that he cannot fly from California to Ohio to visit his children because he is banned from flying due to an arrest about 3 years ago. He is a U.S. citizen and has lived in California all his life.  Can people with minor offenses be stopped at airports in the U.S. because of this?

Comment: You might get a more detailed legal analysis at [Law.SE].

Comment: I just want to clarify does CA = California, not Canada or Central America? It seems to be so

Comment: @axsvl77 that's a good question.  I think "across the U.S." in the title can be taken as a clear indication that "CA" here means California.

Comment: @axsvl77 Yeah, CA being both the state code for California and the country code for Canada does lead to some amusing situations. There's an Ontario in California, too, so I occasionally receive packages shipped from "Ontario, CA, USA," which makes it look like the U.S. annexed Canada.

Comment: @AakashM would "confront him" not be the most obvious answer to your question?

Comment: @ESR and he says 'well those people on the internet are wrong, who do you trust, me or some internet randos?'. Now what? Still can't force him to fly.

Comment: @AakashM what he plans to do with the answer is not related to anything here on travel.se, so these comments are, imo, offtopic. Maybe he just wants to learn the truth, maybe he does want to confront him, it's up to him and has nothing to do with a possible answer.

Comment: @AakashM most of the time, resolving conflicts isn't about forcing someone to do something.

Comment: Sorry to confuse people - CA stands for California so he is just traveling across the country to Ohio.  The situation is rather complicated but by using the story that he cannot fly (is prevented from flying) he does not cover the cost to see his kids but makes others fly with them when the children are required to go see their father.  I would like to prove that he is not banned from flying but don't know exactly how to do that without going through an attorney.  We've spent so much money on that already. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Is he still on parole or something? If not, then he's almost certainly making it up.

Comment: @C.K.Fortman Presumably he could make the journey by train (appreciate this is a long trip, but needs must if the no-fly story is true and he wants to see his children). If his ex-partner is legally obliged to facilitate his access rights by sending the children to him rather than him travelling to them, is it feasible to make arrangements with the airline for the children to fly unaccompanied?

Answer (score 103):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. This person received a DUI or other infraction which resulted in their driver’s license being revoked, which makes it harder to check in for a flight. However, they can apply for a State ID or even a passport for identification purposes if they so choose.
2. They are on a Do-Not-Fly list. This would have to either be because they are thought to be terrorists or have the same name as one. They can [petition to be removed](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/passenger-support/travel-redress-program).
3. The conditions of their bail or parole require them to remain in the same city or county or state. This limits more than flying so would also preclude leaving by car or bus or train. This type of restriction is quite common. It’s also time-delimited so you should be able to ask when this bail- or parole-restriction ends — and travel is often possible with prior permission from the court or parole officer(as @David notes).
4. A variation of #3 is that they have an outstanding warrant in either their origin airport locale, destination locale, or at the federal level  and are afraid that once they present at the airport, they will be arrested. The TSA does not actually check for outstanding warrants as part of normal practice, but the traveler may nonetheless be afraid of that possibility.
5. There may be a restraining order against this individual, perhaps from their former spouse that would make visiting their children difficult, however usually these allow for a third party (for example, grandparents) handoff of kids.
6. They may have a no-trespass order from an airline or an airport but that usually doesn’t preclude going to another airline or airport.
7. This may all be just an excuse not to see their own child for their own reasons.

My guess is that it is item #3 (or #7).

Comment: Might companies put people on #2 for offences short of terrorism?  Such as the case of an airplane forced to make extra landing to remove unruly passenger from the plane?

Comment: @gerrit +1 it’s a possibility but being banned (for example) from Delta wouldn’t mean you couldn’t fly Southwest. I was trying to think of something that would get you banned from all airlines.

Comment: @gerrit the terrorist no fly list is maintained by the government. Companies cannot put people on it.  But they can have their own lists based on facts such as the one you describe.

Comment: As the OP is the parent of the former spouse, I'm guessing he/she would know if it's the fifth possibility.

Comment: The restriction listed as possibility #3 is often that the subject cannot travel out of state *unless permission is first obtained from the parole or probation officer.* And I must add that it's entirely possible that this individual doesn't *want* to travel, and uses his years-old arrest as a pretext.

Comment: @henrik it is still useful for others who may have the same question with slightly different circumstances

Comment: @RoboKaren RE: #2, perhaps a judge could order somebody not fly after repeated criminal incidents

Comment: If you are banned from Airline A and they codeshare with Airline B, you are almost certainly banned from Airline B as well.

Comment: @gerrit [True, like getting intoxicated on a plane and chewing through restraints applied by sky mashalls.](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/fired-rim-execs-chewed-through-restraints-on-flight-1.992829)

Comment: It should be worth noting that the Do-Not-Fly list is seldom, if ever, tied to criminal records (it's looking for patterns indicating terrorist activity). Not only has it [mistakenly added a journalist](https://www.npr.org/2014/09/28/352290026/how-a-journalist-ended-up-on-a-terror-watch-list) (another journalist asked the DHS secretary about it, who promptly got it fixed), it's also been [notoriously hard to find out if you're on it, let alone get off](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2014/03/after-seven-years-exactly-one-person-gets-off-the-govt-no-fly-list/)

Comment: @Machavity Ted Kennedy, a sitting senator at the time, was denied boarding because someone with a similar alias was on the list...

Answer (score 10):

Technically speaking, no.  An arrest is not a conviction and simply being arrested cannot have that kind of punishment.  If he was arrested AND convicted, then yes, it is possible that as either part of his punishment or as part of the conditions of his parole, he is not able to fly.  It is also possible, if he is still pending trial, that he may not be allowed to travel that far away.

Comment: The title says the person in question has a criminal record therefore I think it’s safe to say they were arrested and convicted. As such the first part of this answer is being overly pedantic (and that’s coming from a very pedantic person).

Comment: @Notts90 I was basing that on the text of the question rather than the title.

Comment: Far more likely that he has had some part of his sentence suspended or paroled, and as a condition of that, **he is not allowed to leave the state** without good reason and/or some sort of supervision.  He could fly to Sacramento, but not Guam or Ohio.

Comment: @Kevin the text in the question was ambiguous, the title was not. Why did you decide to go with the question text? This answer would be improved without the arrest vs conviction part, because we know he WAS convicted (he has a record)

Comment: @user79730 _Do_ we know that?  Are you sure OP understands the difference between an arrest record and a criminal record?

Comment: @Harper I'm rather in favor of the hypothesis that the deadbeat ex-son-in-law is falsely claiming to be unable to travel because he wants to avoid the perceived burden of flying halfway across the country to see his kids.

Answer (score 6):

I have traveled out of the country and in the country multiple times with not only someone who has been arrested but with someone who was convicted of manufacturing mushrooms with intent to distribute. They have 2 felonies and are not on probation or parole. So, he is either not telling you the entire story, is just outright lying to you, or is ignorant in this matter.

I suggest to you to call his bluff and tell him you spoke with a criminal lawyer (Someone at work, a friend, a neighbor whatever) and they said there is no reason you can not fly if you are not on a do not fly list, probation, or parole. See what his reponse is, back him into a corner on the issue.

Illegal immigrants can still fly within the USA and tey do not get caught. All you need is an ID and an airline ticket that matches that ID. Well, you also need the will to go. But who am I... just another ignorant person on the internet maybe.